# write logs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to save a traceback from my shiny app (runs on a server). I tried extractStackTrace() with shiny.error(), but the most valuable part of a traceback is truncated, probably, due to a second call of captureStackTraces().

reprex

```
library(shiny)

options(shiny.fullstacktrace = TRUE, shiny.error = function() {
    stack_list <- extractStackTrace(sys.calls())
    print(stack_list)
})

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("action", label = "Action")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$action,{
        sum(3,"g")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For example, I want to get this line from traceback in my reprex
`observeEventHandler [~/app.R#16]`

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM2DG.png)

I would appreciate it if you could help me to find a solution.

Comment: I think this is a good question, as debugging `shiny` is not that easy. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it is possible (would be great to see a solution). Note that `extractStackTrace` [is deprecated](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/stacktrace.html). [This article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html) basically uses `cat`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't use `cat()` because I want to save a trace output after unexpected errors. Traceback, which is printed to the RStudio console by the internal function `printError()`, suits me well. But I don’t understand that argument should I provide to it to save this traceback in a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

Helper functions:

```
# adapt for your purposes
write_error_logs <- function() {
    error <- recover_error()
    
    # cat error message to logfile
    logfile <- paste0(Sys.time(), '.shinylog')
    cat(error$message, '\n', file = logfile)
    
    # format the stack and append to logfile
    stack <- error$stack %>% 
        dplyr::select(-category) %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(num = paste0(num, ':')) %>% 
        tidyr::unite(col = res, sep = ' ') %>% 
        dplyr::pull(res)
    
    stack <- paste0(' ', stack, '\n')
    cat(stack, file = logfile, append = TRUE, sep = '')
}

# adapted from utils::recover
recover_error <- function ()  {

    # get calls
    calls <- sys.calls()
    from <- 0L

    # get frame previous to last stop() call
    n <- length(calls)
    for (i in rev(seq_len(n))) {

        calli <- calls[[i]]
        fname <- calli[[1L]]
        if ( "stop(e)" %in% deparse(calli)) {
            from <- i - 1
            break
        }
    }

    frame <- sys.frame(from)

    # write to logfile
    getError(frame$e)
}

# adapted from shiny::printError
getError <- function (cond,
                      full = get_devmode_option("shiny.fullstacktrace", FALSE),
                      offset = getOption("shiny.stacktraceoffset", TRUE)) {

    error_msg <- sprintf(
        "Error in %s: %s",
        shiny:::getCallNames(list(conditionCall(cond))),
        conditionMessage(cond)
    )

    should_drop <- !full
    should_strip <- !full
    should_prune <- !full

    stackTraceCalls <- c(
        attr(cond, "deep.stack.trace", exact = TRUE),
        list(attr(cond, "stack.trace", exact = TRUE))
    )

    stackTraceParents <- lapply(stackTraceCalls, attr, which = "parents", exact = TRUE)
    stackTraceCallNames <- lapply(stackTraceCalls, shiny:::getCallNames)
    stackTraceCalls <- lapply(stackTraceCalls, shiny:::offsetSrcrefs, offset = offset)

    # Use dropTrivialFrames logic to remove trailing bits (.handleSimpleError, h)
    if (should_drop) {
        # toKeep is a list of logical vectors, of which elements (stack frames) to keep
        toKeep <- lapply(stackTraceCallNames, shiny:::dropTrivialFrames)
        # We apply the list of logical vector indices to each data structure
        stackTraceCalls <- mapply(stackTraceCalls, FUN = `[`, toKeep, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
        stackTraceCallNames <- mapply(stackTraceCallNames, FUN = `[`, toKeep, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
        stackTraceParents <- mapply(stackTraceParents, FUN = `[`, toKeep, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
    }

    delayedAssign("all_true", {
        # List of logical vectors that are all TRUE, the same shape as
        # stackTraceCallNames. Delay the evaluation so we don't create it unless
        # we need it, but if we need it twice then we don't pay to create it twice.
        lapply(stackTraceCallNames, function(st) {
            rep_len(TRUE, length(st))
        })
    })

    # stripStackTraces and lapply(stackTraceParents, pruneStackTrace) return lists
    # of logical vectors. Use mapply(FUN = `&`) to boolean-and each pair of the
    # logical vectors.
    toShow <- mapply(
        if (should_strip) shiny:::stripStackTraces(stackTraceCallNames) else all_true,
        if (should_prune) lapply(stackTraceParents, shiny:::pruneStackTrace) else all_true,
        FUN = `&`,
        SIMPLIFY = FALSE
    )

    dfs <- mapply(seq_along(stackTraceCalls), rev(stackTraceCalls), rev(stackTraceCallNames), rev(toShow), FUN = function(i, calls, nms, index) {
        data.frame(
            num = rev(which(index)),
            call = rev(nms[index]),
            loc = rev(shiny:::getLocs(calls[index])),
            category = rev(shiny:::getCallCategories(calls[index])),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

    res <- list(
        message = error_msg,
        stack = dfs[[1]]
    )

    return(res)
}
```

Example usage:

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.fullstacktrace = TRUE, shiny.error = write_error_logs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("action", label = "Action")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$action,{
        sum(3,"g")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Truncated output written to logfile:

```
Error in sum: invalid 'type' (character) of argument 
 75: h 
 74: .handleSimpleError 
 73: <observer:observeEvent(input$action)>  [#3]
 72: valueFunc 
 71: ..stacktraceon.. 
 70: contextFunc 
 69: env$runWith 
 68: force 
 67: domain$wrapSync 
...
```

Comment: where is the log saved? i tried but couldn't find the saved log file